# Validate archive error, iTunes Store operation failed, Invalid Swift support

Tags: ios, swift

Help me:
Invalid Swift support, The file ***.app/Frameworks/Lib**.a doesn't have the correct file type for this location. Ensure you're using the correct file, rebuild your app using the current public(GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Xcode version 8.3.2